# Use substring to delete part of string in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

In my assignment it's forbidden to use collections and any arrays. We are allowed to use String Tokenizer but any other classes than String and System are not allowed. This solution has to work with any number of entries.

I have a string which look like this :

```
1|Aaron|Peter|3063543030|john@gmail.com + "\n" 
2|Buffet|Anthony|3063543030|john@gmail.com + "\n" 
3|Dunty|Richard|3063543030|john@gmail.com
```

I have this little method to reach the next string index :

```
 public static int nextIndex(int index, String carnet) {
        return carnet.indexOf("\n", index) +1;
        }
```

I have this method in which I delete a substring in the string using substring method :

```
public static String deleteContactFromString (String idContact, String myString) {

        String stringModified = "";
        String myStringModified = "";

        String id = idContact.trim();

        if(!myString.isEmpty()) {

            int start = myString.indexOf(id + "|");

            if (start >= 0) {
            //Here I call the nextIndex method to get next string index
                int end = nextIndex(start, myString);
                
                stringModified = carnet.substring(0, start) + carnet.substring(end);
                myStringModified = stringModified;
                System.out.println("string modified " + myStringModified);
            } else {
                System.out.println("This contact doesnt exist");
                myStringModified = myString;
            }
        }

               return myStringModified;
    }
```

The problem I have is that when myString has only one contact in it, I just can't delete that index because there is no next index. The same problem happen when I try to delete the last index of the string.

If myString is like this and has only one contact :

```
1|Aaron|Peter|3063543030|john@gmail.com + "\n"
```

I can't delete that index.

And if myString has more contacts and I try to delete the last index I have the same problem :

```
1|Aaron|Peter|3063543030|john@gmail.com + "\n" 
2|Buffet|Anthony|3063543030|john@gmail.com + "\n" 
3|Dunty|Richard|3063543030|john@gmail.com <-- Can't be deleted
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me resolve that problem.

Thank's

Comment: I can't get interested in this, because in real life you would use `String#split` here, not iteration.

Comment: Yes I know but in my project I can't use char arrays or any arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nextIndex` method is broken for the last record: Clearly from your examples, the last record may not even end in an `\n`. First you need to think through your protocol on this: What does this mean:

```
1|Aaron|Peter|3063543030|john@gmail.com + "\n" 
2|Buffet|Anthony|3063543030|john@gmail.com + "\n"
```

And it ends there. Is that valid? Should the final newline be stripped? Is this 2 records or 3?

Then, think about this one:

```
1|Aaron|Peter|3063543030|john@gmail.com + "\n" 
2|Buffet|Anthony|3063543030|john@gmail.com
```

from your examples, the intent is clearly that the above is valid and is a 2-record listing.

Your nextIndex code is broken if you're on the last record for the second (last record no newline) case: the `indexOf` call can't find a newline symbol at all, so that evaluates to -1, to which you then add 1, making it look like the next record is back at the start. I assume that's not intentional. You need to write more code here, and check edge cases:

If there is no newline character, then 'the next location' should be `string.length()`. This then conveniently means that `str.substring(that)` is the empty string.